# <sup> taking underline in chrome when given inside an element with text-decoration underline

Tags: html, css, border, underline, text-decorations

tried adjusting the sup tag with custom styling but it breaks when checked across the browsers.  The current code shared http://jsfiddle.net/UXSree/FhVm5/10/ in the fiddle works for firefox and IE but when it comes to webkit browsers it fails. Has anyone come across this?

```
        h1{
    text-decoration:underline;
    width:450px;

    }

    sup{
    color:red;
    font-size: 30%;
    }
```

## This is a multiline heading<sup>with superscript</sup>And here comes the second part of multiline heading<sup>2nd</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the fine tuned solution... http://jsfiddle.net/UXSree/M5WwA/

`h1{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  display: inline;`
}
div{width:200px;border:1px solid red;}

Answer (score 1):

Hey here is a perfect solution

```
h1 {
        text-decoration:underline;
        width:450px;
       display: inline;
    }

    sup {
        color:red;
        font-size: 30%;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gzQa6/1/

Comment: this takes away the underline from superscript. But the requirement is to have the underline for superscript as well but it has to be aligned with the h1 underline.

Comment: hey kapil we are back to square one, this breaks in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

```
   h1 {
        text-decoration:underline;
        width:450px;
       display: inline;
    }

    sup {
        color:red;
        font-size: 30%;
        text-decoration:none; display: inline-block;
    }
```

The above is not an ideal solution, but it does work.

Comment: this takes away the underline from superscript. But the requirement is to have the underline for superscript as well but it has to be aligned with the h1 underline.